# Django: Custom Metaclass Inheriting From And Extending `ModelBase`

Tags: python, django, inheritance, metaclass, method-resolution-order

I am trying to do some metaclass hocus-pocus. I want my own Metaclass
to inherit from `ModelBase` and then I want to add additional logic by
extending its `__new__` method. However I think there is something
strange happening with the MRO/inheritance order in the way I'm using it.

Here is the basic situation:

```
from django.db.models import Model, ModelBase


class CustomMetaclass(ModelBase):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        # As I am trying to extend `ModelBase`, I was expecting this
        # call to `super` to give me the return value from here:

        # https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L300

        # And that I would be able to access everyhing in `_meta` with
        # `clsobj._meta`. But actually this object is
        # `MyAbstractModel` and has no `_meta` property so I'm pretty
        # sure `__new__` isn't being called on `ModelBase` at all at
        # this point.
        clsobj = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

        # Now, I want to have access to the `_meta` property setup by
        # `ModelBase` so I can dispatch on the data in there. For
        # example, let's do something with the field definitions.
        for field in clsobj._meta.get_fields():
            do_stuff_with_fields()

        return clsobj


class MyAbstractModel(metaclass=CustomMetaclass):
    """This model is abstract because I only want the custom metaclass
    logic to apply to those models of my choosing and I don't want to
    be able to instantiate it directly. See the class definitions below.
    """
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class MyModel(Model):
    """Regular model, will be derived from metaclass `ModelBase` as usual.
    """
    pass

class MyCustomisedModel(MyAbstractModel):
    """This model should enjoy the logic defined by our extended `__new__` method.
    """
    pass
```

Any ideas why `__new__` on `ModelBase` isn't being called by
`CustomMetaClass`? How can I correctly extend `ModelBase` in this way? I'm pretty sure metaclass inheritance is possible
but seems like I'm missing something...

Comment: Your code looks fine except that you need to return `clsobj` in `__new__`.

Comment: Yep, fine I am actually doing that but I omitted it for brevity; I have added it to the above. It doesn't however answer the question as I have indicated I need the object coming back from `__new__` in `ModelBase` well before my custom `__new__` method returns anything.

Comment: Yeah. Your comment in `CustomMetaclass .__new__` says it all. `ModelBase.__new__` is called, just that accessing an unset `_meta` attribute breaks it because `ModelBase.__new__` [returns early when there are no bases](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/db/models/base.py#L89)

Comment: What you can do is declare Model as a base. e.g. `MyAbstractModel(Model, metaclass=CustomMetaclass)`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule excellent catch on the early return, I did overlook that. Adding `Model` won't work as you suggest however as the `AppRegistry` isn't loaded. I've got a solution though I think, I will post it as a full answer asap.

Comment: Sounds good. Looking forward to your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to get a `clsobj` with the `_meta` attribute is as simple as:

```
class CustomMetaclass(ModelBase):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        bases = (Model,)
        clsobj = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

        for field in clsobj._meta.get_fields():
            do_stuff_with_fields()

        return clsobj
```

And we can do the same thing with `MyAbstractModel(Model, metaclass=CustomMetaclass)`.

But, ultimate success here still depends on the kind of work we intend to do in the `__new__` method. If we want to somehow introspect and work with the class's fields using metaprogramming, we need to be aware that we are trying to rewrite the class using `__new__` at **import** time and thus (because this is Django) the [app registry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#application-registry) is not yet ready and this can cause exceptions to be raised if certain conditions arise (e.g. we are forbidden to access or work with reverse relations). This happens here even when `Model` is passed into `__new__` as a base.

We can half-circumvent some of those problems by using the following non-public call to `_get_fields` (which Django does itself in certain places):

```
class CustomMetaclass(ModelBase):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        bases = (Model,)
        clsobj = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

        for field in clsobj._meta._get_fields(reverse=False):
            do_stuff_with_fields()

        return clsobj
```

But depending on the scenario and what we are trying to achieve we might still hit problems; for example, we won't be able to access any reverse relations using our metaclass. So still no good.

To overcome this restriction we have to leverage signals in the app registry to make our classes as dynamic as we want them to be with full access to `_meta.get_fields`.

See this ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24231

The main takeaway being: "a Django model class is not something you are permitted to work with outside the context of a prepared app registry."